# Heap corruption upon free( )

Tags: c

I've been getting heap corruption error when calling the free() function. The project worked in VC++ 2010. The whole building process is working ok, but in run-time I get the error: (CircularQueue is name of my project)

> ERRORS:
>
> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in CircularQueue.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in
>   CircularQueue.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while CircularQueue.exe
>   has focus.
>
> The output window may have more diagnostic information.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>


#include "CircularQ.h"

#define max 4
//char circQ[10][3145728];

Image_details_t circQ[max],*ptr[max];
Image_details_t *temp;
LONG q[10],front=0,rear=-1;
#if 1
void main()
{

    int ch;
    //void insert();    
    insert("h",1,1,1,1);
    insert("h",1,1,1,1);
    insert("h",1,1,1,1);
    delet();
    delet();
    delet();
    delet();
    while(1);
}

#endif

void insert(char *img,int channel,int imgWidth,int imgHeight,int imgLen)
{
    //int x;
    //char x[20];
    int l = 0;  

    if((front==0&&rear==max-1)||(front>0&&rear==front-1))
        printf("Queue is overflow\n");
    else
    {       
        l = strlen(img);
        //scanf("%d",&x);
        if(rear==max-1&&front>0)
        {
            printf("hello i m here");
            InterlockedCompareExchange( &rear,0,rear);
            circQ[rear].img = (char *) malloc(1);
            strcpy(circQ[rear].img,img);
            circQ[rear].channel = channel;
            circQ[rear].imgWidth = imgWidth;
            circQ[rear].imgHeight = imgHeight;
            circQ[rear].imgLen = imgLen;            

            //q[rear]=x;
        }
        else
        {
            if((front==0&&rear==-1)||(rear!=front-1))
            {
                InterlockedExchangeAdd(&rear,1);
                circQ[rear].img = (char *)malloc(l);
                strcpy(circQ[rear].img,img);
                circQ[rear].channel = channel;
                circQ[rear].imgWidth = imgWidth;
                circQ[rear].imgHeight = imgHeight;
                circQ[rear].imgLen = imgLen; 
                //q[rear]=x;
            }
        }
    }
}
void  delet()
{
    char a[20];
    //  char *temp;

    if((front==0)&&(rear==-1))
    {
        printf("Queue is underflow\n");
        return;
        //exit(0);
    }
    if(front==rear)
    {
        //a=q[front];
        strcpy(a,circQ[front].img);
        //temp = circQ[front];
        //free(temp);
        //free(circQ[rear].img);
        InterlockedCompareExchange( &rear,-1,rear);
        InterlockedCompareExchange( &front,0,front);
    }
    else
        if(front==max-1)
        {
            //a=q[front];
            strcpy(a,circQ[front].img); 
            //free(circQ[rear].img);
            //temp = circQ[front];
            //free(temp);
            InterlockedCompareExchange( &front,0,front);
        }
        else
            {

                strcpy(a,circQ[front].img);
                //free(circQ[rear].img);
                temp = &circQ[front];
                free(temp);              // in this part problem is occurring
                InterlockedExchangeAdd(&front,1);
                //a=q[front];
            }
        printf("Deleted element is:%s\n",a);
        free(&circQ[front]);


}
```

**Header file:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdint.h>    

typedef struct Image_details
{    
    char *img;    
    int channel;    
    int imgWidth;    
    int imgHeight;      
    int imgLen;
}Image_details_t;    

void insert(char *img,int channel,int imgWidth,int imgHeight,int imgLen);
void  delet();
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You are freeing a non-heap variable, you shouldn't, remove this

   ```
   free(&circQ[front]);
   ```
2. You allocate space for `img` member, just one byte, an empty string requires one byte for the terminating `'\0'`, you then do `strcpy()` which is meant for strings, i.e. non-`nul` sequence of bytes followed by a `nul`, byte.

   Maybe you mean

   ```
   memcpy(circQ[rear].img, img, 1);
   ```

   which is also the same as

   ```
   circQ[rear].img[0] = img[0];
   ```
3. You should check the return value of `malloc()`.
4. You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()`, if you need to then you are using either the wrong compiler, or the wrong programming language.

Comment: i hv tried with free(&circQ[front].img) also but still i m getting same problem

Comment: Because it should be `free(circQ[from].img);` without the `&` address of operator. Also, if `img` will always hold just one byte, don't `malloc()` it, make it `char img[1]`.

Comment: and space allocated for img member is not 1 Its variable ' L '

Comment: @AnuragSharma please post the header file.

Comment: Did you remove `free(temp)`?

Comment: You should use `memcpy()` instead of `strcpy()` and remove almost every `free()` the only thing that should be `free()`ed is anything that was `malloc()`ed.

Comment: And did you replace `strcpy()` with `memcpy()`?

Comment: ohh now its working but it is inly working while i m giving 1 as third parameter that is size... while i m giving more than that it is again giving same error

Comment: You need to read more about poitners and dynamic memory instead of just trying to make it work, also I'd suggest using linux, there are very nice tools to debug memory errors, I don't know about windows but for linux I highly recommend [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org).